# Checksum inconsistencies in reading large files within same server. Hardware issue symptoms?

Tags: hardware, large-files, memory-corruption

I'm having checksums inconsistencies in one server, and would like to know your opinion and similar experiences you may have had.

Every time I run the command

`# md5sum  MyBig.3GB.largeFile.bin`

the checksum output is different. Even for this command:

`#  for i in {1..10} ; do time md5sum  MyBig.3GB.largeFile.bin  ;done`

the subsequent checksum output is different, and the time taken to run each iteration is also very different and perhaps random, from 10 secs up to 3 minutes, which is the usual time based on I/O performance.

The issue is not only with the 'md5sum' checksum, but also with 'cksum' and 'sha1sum'. Same inconsistent results.

I have three twin servers, with exactly the same specs. Only one of them is showing this problem. 
The server is in the testing phase, no real end-users yet. Although you only see this behaviour when the server is stressed and put under heavy load. And this is important, you reboot the server and the problem disappears, until is pushed to its limits again, then it starts to show those symptoms.

The server is an ASUS motherboard, Intel Xeon i7 CPU, 4x8GB kingston RAM, SATA controller Intel 8 Series/C220, 2x2TB Seagate ST2000DM in RAID-1 software, running CentOS 6.4  64bit.

From my experience, this is a clear symptom of a hardware potential problem. However, the server owner (i'm just renting those servers) ran a memory test, and denies any hardware related issue. The server is brand new. The memory tests didn't show any memory problem.

Now, this is the question to you all.  What do you think?  what could be the problem? 
have you had any similar issues in the past.

Thanks.

(Sorry for the long description)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a memory problem to me. Or otherwise some other hardware error.

It seems really unlikely that it's a software problem. You're correct, tell the server owner to try harder or to test other systems like the PCI interconnects and the drives themselves.

Comment: Thank-you. I agree.
How can you tell the owner - 'hey, you have a problem with those SIMM memory chips', when the memory tests results didn't throw any error?

Comment: Ask him if he can run the tests longer or with more stress going on? Or maybe ask him to run disk/cpu tests, too?